# How does one compile libqt4 OR wkhtmtltopdf for Solaris?

Tags: webkit, solaris, opensolaris

Anyone have REALLY specific and accurate information about which libraries I need in order to compile both libqt and wkhtmltopdf in Solaris?

Comment: I know it's an old question, but I'm curious about the same thing. The compilation page (http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/compilation) has some instructions, but if you look at all the comments from "david.pa...@suranyami.com", you'll see that you run into lots of issues on Solaris. Not sure if that guy ever got it working...

Comment: Update: and according to this thread, David may have given up on the attempt to compile on Solaris: http://www.mail-archive.com/rails-oceania@googlegroups.com/msg04871.html